# Pdf generated from scrollview using PdfDocument only prints contents of first page keeping other pages blank

Tags: android, android-scrollview, pdfdocument

I want to generate a pdf document using Android's [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) class by scrolling through contents of a scrollView.

Right now, correct number of pages are being generated but contents are printed only on first page of pdf. Other generated pages remain blank.

```
  
public void toPdf(ScrollView view) {
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
    int pageHeight = view.getHeight();
    int totalHeight = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();

    int pageCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) totalHeight / pageHeight);
    
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, 1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    int savedContentOffset = view.getScrollY();
    int savedContentInset = view.getPaddingBottom();

    view.setClickable(false);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pageCount; pageIndex++) {
      view.scrollTo(0, pageIndex * pageHeight);
      view.draw(canvas);
      document.finishPage(page);
      if (pageIndex < pageCount - 1) {
        pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, pageIndex + 2).create();
        page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        canvas = page.getCanvas();
      }
    }

    view.scrollTo(savedContentOffset, 0);
    view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, savedContentInset);
    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    // save PDF to a file
    savePdfDocument(document);
  }
```

I verified the position of scrollview is being updated correctly. I also tried adding delays between each scroll to ensure the view's contents are written in pdf but it did not help. I am not able to figure why are contents not being written to pdf on other pages except the first page. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that scrolling is done by canvas translate (pan the canvas) and when you are calling `view.scrollTo` you are translating the canvas for the screen but you are then asking the view to draw itself to a new `canvas` that has not had the pan translation applied to it but the clipBounds on the view have been set.

Thus the scroll view contents is actually drawn off the bottom on the second page.

A better way to draw the contents of a scrollview type view is actually re-measure and layout all the children of the scrollview in turn and then add them to a linear layout that is drawn to each page if they will fit.

This is better because you won't get a child view that is split across a pdf page as you are likely to with your current method.

The concept of re-measuring and then laying out to a linearlayout for each page is shown in the example https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf while this might be for a recyclerview the concept would be the same except instead of iterating through the adaptor creating each view from the viewholder you would iterate through the children view.

e.g.

```
for(int index = 0; index < ((ViewGroup) viewGroup).getChildCount(); index++) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup) viewGroup).getChildAt(index);
}
```

This also allow you to create PDF pages of standard sizes if you want.

As a side note you might be able to replace `view.scrollTo(0, pageIndex * pageHeight);`

with `canvas.translate(0, pageIndex * pageHeight);` to apply the correct translation to the pdf's canvas as well (not ever tried this as it won't produce the best results)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using `canvas.translate(0, pageIndex * pageHeight)` did not help. I think re-measuring and then laying out to a linearlayout for each page should not be required given that everything else is working correctly in code. The correct number of pages are being generated and offset if being updated. Most likely am missing something from the way I am drawing to pdf that is causing it to not draw once scroll happens after first page. Not sure what is missing though

Comment: While it might not be required, it produces a lot better results to re-measure and layout (and actually works). If you manage it get it to print a scrollview then the pdf won't print very well, if you just want the pdf to be viewed on screen and you don't go for standard pages sizes then you might as well just go for one large page pdf. The only other thing I can think of is try debugging the ClipBounds area and setting it to the right values or may be `view.setClipBounds(null)` to draw all of the view.